# Add Lightning Avatars into a list of Different Results from a Customized SearchBar

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, list, js

I have a search bar which is showing the Users, Queues and Public Groups from the ORG, when you  start typing on the search bar the different objects start to appear. I want to  show the results with different avatars depending of what it is, so if the possible results are:

- Queues-> show standard:queue
- Public Groups-> show standard:groups
- User-> show standard:avatar (or if it's possible show the avatar based on the user sex)
- Have some space between results.

I can't find much documentation on how to use the LWC avatar, I think I should loop through the possible results in JS, but I am not sure how to call the LWC avatar there.

My HTML for the moment is like this:

```
       <!--search box, input box + -->
                                <lightning-input type="text" id="combobox-id-16" value={userName} 
                                    onchange={handleKeyChange} onkeydown={handleClick} onclick={handleClick}
                                    onblur={handleClick} aria-activedescendant="option1" label='Find User or Group'
                                    aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-12" role="textbox"
                                    placeholder="Search...">
                                </lightning-input>   
                                <template if:true={showSearchedValues}>
                                    <div class="slds-box" style="height: 130px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                                        <ul class="" role="">
                                            <template for:each={usersGroupList} for:item="userObj" >
                                                <li  class="slds-p-around_x-mall" key={userObj.id} data-value={userObj.id}
                                                data-label={userObj.name} style="cursor: pointer;" onclick={handleParentSelection}>
                                                
                                                <lightning-avatar key={userObj.id} src="/bad/image/url.jpg" 
                                                fallback-icon-name="standard:avatar"  
                                                alternative-text="User,Queue or Public Group"
                                                size="small" 
                                                class="slds-m-right_small"> 
                                                </lightning-avatar> {userObj.name}: {userObj.type} 
                                                </li>
                                            </template>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            
                            </div>
                            <!-- Start : Parent Search Result -->
                            <div if:true={messageResult}>
                                No Result Found!
                            </div>
```

JS code

```
//call data for SearchBar
import getAllUsersGroups from '@salesforce/apex/UserGroupsController.getAllUsersGroups';
//call data for Dual Listbox
import fetchQueuesPubGrps from '@salesforce/apex/UserGroupsController.fetchQueuesPubGrps';
import addRemove from '@salesforce/apex/UserGroupsController.addRemove';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class SearchBar extends LightningElement {

    //declare properties search bar
    @track userName = '';
    @track userList = []; 
    @track usersGroupList=[];
    @track groupList=[];    
    @track objectApiName = 'User'
    @track userFound = false;
    @track messageResult=false; //not found message
    @track isShowResult = true;   
    @track showSearchedValues = false;  
    @track selectedUser;
 
    onLeave(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.userName = "";
            this.usersGroupList = null;
        }, 300);
    }

    //calling data to for the searchbar
    @wire(getAllUsersGroups, {uName:'$userName'})
    retrieveUsers ({error, data}) {
       this.messageResult=false;
       if (data) {
           console.log('dataForSearch::'+ JSON.stringify (data));
           if(data.length>0 && this.isShowResult){
               this.usersGroupList = data;                
               this.showSearchedValues = true; 
               this.messageResult=false;
           }            
           else if(data.length==0){
               this.usersGroupList = [];                
               this.showSearchedValues = false;
               if(this.userName!='')
                   this.messageResult=true;               
           }       
       } else if (error) {
           this.selectedUser =  '';
           this.userName =  '';
           this.userList=[];           
           this.showSearchedValues = false;
           this.messageResult=true;   
       }
   }
   
   handleClick(event){
       this.isShowResult = true;
       this.messageResult=false;
       this.userFound=false;
    }

    handleKeyChange(event){
        this.messageResult=false;
        this.userName = event.target.value;
        this.userFound=false;
    }
    
    handleParentSelection(event){
        console.log('parentEventID'+ (event.target.dataset.value));
        console.log('parentEvent'+ JSON.stringify(event.target.dataset));
        this.showSearchedValues = false;
        this.isShowResult = false; //to avoid overwritting groupList
        this.messageResult=false;
        this.userName =  event.target.dataset.label;      
        console.log('userName::'+this.userName); 
        this.selectedUser = event.target.dataset.value; 
        console.log('selectedUser:'+this.selectedUser);
        
        // Dispatches the event.
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: this.id });
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
    
    //showModal
    handleShowSelectedObject(event){
        const modal=  this.template.querySelectorAll(c-groups-modal);
        modal.show();
}
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

when you are retrieving the data and assigning it to a proerty `this.usersGroupList = data;`  instead of directly assigning it, you can parse through the data to determine the type, and assign an icon type.

```
this.prop = data.map(item => { return {...item, icon : (item.type === 'some type ) ? 'icon#1' : 'icon#2' } }
```

the above example is just for reference purposes, basically, you use the map function to go through each data item, assign the values using a spread operator, and finally, add an icon property to the object based on the type. That way, wen you are iterating in your template, you can assign a different "avatar" or "icon" to the displayed item.